# difference between equivalent and equal sign

Tags: notation, terminology

I am reading a statement in which we have to show that $f(x)$ is equivalent to $0$ on an interval.

What is differences $f(x)$ is $0$ and  $f(x)$ is equivalently $0$ on an interval.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Peter Woolfitt's answer answers your question nicely, so I am only adding that this "confusion" arises because it is customary to not really make a distinction between a function and a function's value on an element of its domain. So $f(x)$ both denotes the function $f$ and the value it takes on $x$. The expression $f(x)=0$ can mean that for some $x$, the function takes $0$ value, and that $x$ needs to be found, while $f(x)\equiv 0$ means that $f$ is the zero function.

Answer (score 6):

People write $f(x)\equiv0$ on an interval to mean that the function is identically $0$ on the interval - that is the only value $f(x)$ takes is on the interval is $0$. This notation is sometimes used to avoid confusion that arises with $f(x)=0$ which looks like one is attempting to solve the question which $x$ satisfy $f(x)=0$.